# Powershell incrementing with four digits

Tags: powershell

I'd like to rename a batch of files with an incremental number included in the file name, however I want the numbers to maintain four digits with 0s as place holder (0001, 0002 etc.).

I believe I have to format the incremental increase with `'{0:d4}' -f $variable` but cant figure it out. The following code is fine for numbers in double digits, example: 0010 but only produces three digits for 1-9 example: 001, 002 etc.

How to I employ the formatting for four digit incremental numbers?

```
$number = 00
$files = GCI "C:\work\" -filter *.jpg

foreach($file in $files){
    $name = $file.BaseName.Split(".")[0]
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName ("$name`_" + ($number++) + "_.jpg")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-f` operator to automatically zero-pad the value:

```
$number = 0
$files = GCI "C:\work\" -filter *.jpg

foreach($file in $files){
    $name = $file.BaseName.Split(".")[0]
    $newName = '{0}_{1:0000}_.jpg' -f $name,($number++)
    $file | Rename-Item -NewName $newName
}
```

The formatting string `0000` just means "left-pad value with 0's up to length 4"

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I'm still not sure I understand how the formatting is passed to the ++ incrementing without a command, guess that's just how it's intended to work. Will do some more reading. Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

most languages will have a ++ operator and it basically means add 1 to this value. So it is basically saying
$number = $number + 1